# Issue with Jpa and inheritance

Tags: java, vaadin, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, vaadin8

I've tried to implement some sort of inheritance between 2 classes but eclipse-link fails  at the end.
I've got a `Product` class:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="product")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "product_type_desc", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Product
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="id")
   private int id;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "product_model_id")
   private ProductModel productModel;
}
```

And a `ProductModel` class:

```
@Table(name="product_model")
@DiscriminatorValue("product_model")
public class ProductModel extends Product
{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "productModel")
    private Product product;
}
```

I've then created a `DataProvider` using the `Product` class and use it in a `Grid`. Everything is working fine until I want to filter it on a `@ManyToOne` property.

I get the following errors

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't0.id' in 'order clause'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT t1.id AS a1, t1.product_model_id AS a89 FROM product_model t1 WHERE (t1.disabled = ?) ORDER BY t0.id DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

There's 2 error:

1. Instead of using the product table, it use product_model
2. There's a t0 alias in the ORDER BY that's nowhere else...

Here's what I think is happening:

1. Eclipse link correctly build the query using the product table with t0 as alias
2. when it build the SELECT it somehow thinks it need product_model and not product
3. it update the FROM and change the alias to t1 (but don't change the ORDER BY)

I've also tried using a `ClassExtractor` but no change.

Aditional informations:

1. We are using EclipseLink 2.7.12
2. We are using JavaX Persistence 2.2.1
3. We are using the Criteria API

Comment: If Vaadin is not relevant to the problem, please consider removing the
tags.

Comment: Seems like something likely isolated to TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance. Would joined inheritance be an option? If it works, you may want to file a bug